# Reset Webcam Settings to defaults

Tags: xubuntu, webcam

I installed Camorama as part of a  test on video capture performance under xubuntu 12.04.

I played around with some of the effects settings -afterward I realized that Camorama doesn't apply Image processing to the frames it reads from the webcam, instead it appears to alter some settings on the webcam device itself, as every other app that uses the webcam now shows the video feed with same tint / contrast etc as set under Camorama.

I tried to reset the settings in Camorama without any look, I tried to set the settings to look some way normal also without any luck! is there some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple to reset a webcam to it defaults settings using luvcview

1. Install luvcview:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install luvcview
   ```
2. Start application:

   ```
   luvcview
   ```
3. Click the reset button in the GUI:

[image: Luvcview, after click the reset buton]

If this doesn't work, there are other solutions at the 
[Ubuntus webcam troubleshooting page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting) (section 6)

Comment: Is there a way to install this on 18.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

`luvcview` is no longer available in newer versions of Ubuntu.

As a replacement, you can use `guvcview`.

`guvcview` is available in Ubuntu's `universe` repository.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to purge camorama package or **completely*** remove it via synaptic package manager *it means all settings and config will be deleted.

Comment: sorry tried this too? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam

Comment: Thanks.. figured out how to reset it, after finding a link to the webcam trouble shooting page via that link..